# Python: Create a global variable from a string?

Tags: python

Is there a way to create a global variable from a string? I know that you can make a variable from a string like so:

```
    string = 'hello'
    val = 10
    vars()[string] = val
```

Thus making hello a variable equal to 10. I do not know how to make that user input variable global however, this does not work:

```
    string = 'hello'
    val = 10
    vars()[string] = val
    eval("global " + string)
```

Comment: Why do you need this? Why don't you use a dictionary? That would be much cleaner.

Comment: Just as a side observation: in over a decade writing Python, I've never - literally not once - ever needed to do anything remotely close to this.

Comment: Why do you criticize this question? There are surely legitimate uses for this. And if not, knowing how it can be done from a purely curious standpoint is legitimate as well, is it not?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use the `globals()` function:

```
name = "hello"
globals()[name] = 10
```

Comment: @user1424641 check as answer then ?

Comment: @user1424641: If you have to do this, there is probably something wrong with your implementation.

Comment: I thought this method was extremely unsafe... I'm trying to set globals in a local (module) namespace... not sure if `sys.modules[current_module]` would be a good spot to define the global name.

Comment: EDIT: oh, it's clarified here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311033/creating-a-global-variable-from-a-string-from-within-a-class?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Setting global variables from module:

I tried to something similar in attempt to simplify my version of argparse so it would allow the minimal duplication of names, support case insensitive multiple character flags but still set global variables with mixed case flags.
The Only solution I could come up with was to return a statement list which I could exec.  My attempts to exec within the module were not successful.
My example:

## Self test

```
def main():
    print "Some tests with provided args"

    One = 1
    Two = 2
    Three = 3

    prs = ArgumentParserCI(description='process cmdline args')
    prs.add_argument('One')
    prs.add_argument('Three')
    cmdlineargs = ['-one', 'one', '--thr', "III"]
    argsdict, unknownargs, execlist = prs.parse_args(cmdlineargs)
    exec(execlist)
    print("cmdlineargs:", cmdlineargs)
    print (One, Two, Three)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Printout:

```
Some tests with provided args
('cmdlineargs:', ['-one', 'one', '--thr', 'III'])
('one', 2, 'III')
```