# How to make a variable from each element of the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, variables

For example, I have 2 lists `['name', 'age', 'id']` and `['John', '20', '441']`.
I want to get output:

```
name = John
age = 20
id = 441
```

That is, from the elements of 1 list to make the names of variables.
Given that the elements of list 1 are always different.

Update: I want to get a variable `name` with value *"John"*, `age` with value *'20'* and etc.

Comment: Can you explain why would you need to create variables? Look for dictionaries.

Comment: Do you want to create the *variables*, or do you want to create the *code to create the variables*? I.e. is your desired output a variable ``name`` with value ``"John"``, or the string ``"name = 'John'"``?

Comment: A variable name with value "John"

Answer (score 7):

You can use a dictionary for this.

```
vars=['name', 'age', 'id']
dets=['John', '20', '441']
details={k:v for k,v in zip(vars,dets)}
```

You can do this instead of a dict comprehension.

```
dict(zip(vars,dets))
```

---

```
details['name']
#'John'
details['age']
#'20'
```

---

Not recommended but you can use [`globals`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals).

```
for var, det in zip(vars,dets):
    globals()[var]=det
```

---

```
>>>name
'John'
>>>age
'20'
```

Comment: A more compact way will be to use the `dict` constructor directly: `dict(zip(vars, dets))`

Comment: @Tomerikoo yes, but I actually posted the same but it wasn't well-recieved in this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/60464003/12416453 So, I posted this. I'll `dict(zip(vars,dets))` to the answer though as it seems more pythonic but some may argue about it.

Comment: @Ch3steR,.. which does not mean the compact one is any worse.

Comment: I don't see any down-votes or negative comments... What makes you say it's not well-recieved? It is a prefectly Pythonic way of doing this

Comment: @Tomerikoo Actually they were retracted after a long debate about it.

Comment: Ah I see. Well it might be because the situation there was a bit different as the dictionary was already existed so one might argue that it could lead to side effects. But here this is exactly the use-case for using the `dict(zip(...))` construct...

Comment: On second look at the accepted answer there, I really don't see why would anyone claim yours was wrong... Anyway, doing `{k: v for k,v in zip(x, y)}` is just the longer, explicit way of `dict(zip(x, y))`

Comment: @Tomerikoo Agreed, Good point. `zip` only zips until one of the iterable is consumed that may be the case for not using `zip` in that question.

Comment: @Tomerikoo Maybe it just comes down to preferences. Some prefer explicit and some implicit but `{k:v for k,v in zip(x,y)}` isn't pythonic IMO.

Comment: @Austin Completely agreed. And `dict(zip(vars,dets))` is more pythonic way to do IMO.

Comment: Why is `globals()[var]=det` not recommended? I saw that being criticized [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806327/python-create-a-global-variable-from-a-string) too but I don't see why that would be wrong.

Comment: @revliscano It's clarified [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311033/creating-a-global-variable-from-a-string-from-within-a-class?rq=1)

Answer (score -2):

Program:

```
label = ['name', 'age', 'id']
val = ['John', '20', '441']

for x,y in zip(label,val):
    print(x,y)
```

Output:

```
name John
age 20
id 441
```

Comment: The question has now been updated to clarify the intention is to define variables.