# Python: Extract all values in a dictionary into assignment statements?

Tags: python, dictionary, variable-assignment

For a dictionary 
`d={'foo1': 1, 'foo2': 2, 'foo3': 3}`, what is the most efficient way to assign the strings to their definitions:

```
foo1=1
foo2=2
foo3=3
```

When no assignment statements are used, I need to call the entry with the dictionary, eg. `d['foo1']`, but I don't plan to use this.

Note: Thanks for pointing out that it was a string. However, I am now assigning the string terms to their corresponding values in the dictionary.

Comment: `globals().update(d)` if you're setting global variables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Create a global variable from a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806327/python-create-a-global-variable-from-a-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
locals().update(d)
```

Comment: Nice pointing out `update()`, was unaware that it took a dictionary : )

Comment: This doesn't work. Locals only gives you a view. You cannot use it to add, delete or change the contents of a variable. You can mutate a referenced object, but that's different. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals

Comment: Does `globals` make a difference?

Comment: Yes. Globals are stored in a dict internally. Globals just gives you access to that dict. Locals are stored differently. The function creates a dict from the underlying storage implementation.

Comment: So what if I'm not updating the dictionary?

Comment: Then you're fine. But that means you can't use `dict.update`. You have to do stuff like: `locals()[name].attr = new_value`. It makes your implementation fragile. Just use a dict and stop trying to force locals to do something it's not meant for. If you really must, then create an object and update its internal `__dict__`. Eg. `obj.name` becomes `vars(obj)["name"]`

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> globals()['test'] = 10
>>> test
10
```

Not the most pretty way, but it works.

```
d = {'foo1': 1, 'foo2': 2, 'foo3': 3}
for key, val in d.items():
    globals()[key] = val
print(foo1)
```

(Or use locals(), but Colin beat me to it)

Comment: May I understand how 'test' relates to my examples above?

Comment: @teachmyselfhowtocode It was a example of how you can assign variables via "strings", your solution is the two rows below. The first was just a test so you can see the principle of how it works.